# A select statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval

Tags: sql-server

For example, I had a variable `@rev` for data retrieval as shown in this query:

```
select distinct    
    @accNo, illness_id, desc_id, 'Lab', labname,
    lr.Result, 'positive', 'false', @sex

@rev = case 
          when datediff(day, @admitdate, lr.LabDateTime) < 0 
             then 1 
             else datediff(day, @admitdate, lr.LabDateTime) 
       end
```

I want to use this variable in the same select query `where` clause as

```
L.LabDateTime between @admitdate and dateadd(hh, 24 * @rev, @admitdate)
```

Can I get that var value there ..?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking as it's currently written. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you are assigning the column values from a SELECT statement into local variables but not all columns are assigned to a corresponding local variable.

May be you can try this way

```
select @rev=case when DATEDIFF(day,@admitdate,lr.LabDateTime)<0 then 1 else DATEDIFF(day,@admitdate,lr.LabDateTime) end
select distinct @accNo,illness_id,desc_id,'Lab',labname,lr.Result,'positive','false',@sex,@rev
```